# Javascript loading more content with AJAX problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, window, height

So I've been learning javascript for 2 months now and I decided to make a scroll  thing where when you scroll the page you get more content (more paragraphs in div). I watched tutorial on youtube and did something like that but it doesn't work as i expected. At first it looks like it works but i noticed that i don't  need to scroll down(or to scroll to bottom) to load more content but can go scroll up as well. To save you some time (if not interested in reading whole script) this is what i am checking (code near the end of the script):

```
 $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $("#load_data").height()
```

Which is in Vanilla JS from my understanding this:

```
 window.innerHeight + window.scrollY > document.querySelector('#load_div').offsetHeight
```

scrollTop() and scrollY should return(or set) value of pixels from the top of window(in this case) scrolled. Then we add inner height of window. Here is what i don't understand then, Shouldn't those 2 always be bigger then the divs height? So that explains why wherever i scroll it triggers. But how to set this up so it only triggers when i am at the bottom or near it? Here is full code (without php response part which only returns paragraph that got data from database):

```
            <div id="load_data"></div>
            <div id="load_data_message"></div>

        </div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
            var limit = 8;
            var start = 0;
            var action = 'inactive';
                function load_data(limit, start){

                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'infinitload.php',
                        method: 'POST',
                        data: {limit: limit, start: start},
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(data){
                            $('#load_data').append(data);  //Appending data;

                        if(data == ''){ 
                        $('#load_data_message').html('<button>No results found</button>');
                        action = 'active';//if
                        }else{
                           $('#load_data_message').html('<button>Loading Content</button>');
                           action = 'inactive';
                        }//else

                        }//success
                    })//ajax      
                }//load_data()

                //Loading for the first time
            if(action == 'inactive'){
                action = 'active';
                load_data(limit, start);
            }

            $(window).scroll(function(){
             if( $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $("#load_data").height() && action == 'inactive'){
                 $('button:contains("Loading Content")').toggle();
                 action = 'active';
                 start = start + limit;
                 setTimeout(function(){
                     load_data(limit, start);
                 }, 1500);
             }
            });
        });//dom ready

        </script>


    </body>
```

UPDATE:
I tried code like this http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/gWD66/
which totally makes sense and it works in example there but not in my case. Confused. It's probably something else leading to my problem so i ll try to look into my code again. Thanks for all replies.

Comment: Does the entire page scroll, or does a subsection of the page scroll?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Entire page

Comment: One approach I have done in the past is to throw an empty span after the container that the loaded content will be appended to.  Then it is a pretty simple check to see if the offsetTop of that element is >= the scroll distance of the window.  If it's >=, the user has scrolled enough so that the element is in their view, indicating more content needs to be added.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
$("#load_data").height()
```

with

```
$("#load_data").offset().top
```

Comment: You should do something with action == 'inactive' as well

Comment: $("#load_data").height() returns height of that element not offset

Answer (score 0):

Problem is finally fixed. I forgot html DOCTYPE thing. Never got annoyed more :)